# XSLT Setting property values conditionally

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am after some help please as I am struggling with some basic XSLT. I have used variables in a number of ways before but I need to be able to set property values of my layout conditionally:

```
<xsl:variable name="VAR_pagewidth" select="'21cm'"/>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <fo:layout-master-set>      
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="$VAR_pagewidth" margin-top="0.5cm"  margin-bottom="1cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="15mm" margin-left="16mm" margin-right="26mm" margin-bottom="45mm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-first" extent="0mm" margin-left="1mm" margin-right="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-normal" extent="42mm" />
                <fo:region-end border-top-width="5pt" region-name="right-sidebar" writing-mode="tb-rl" extent="10mm" />                 
            </fo:simple-page-master>

    </fo:layout-master-set>
```

I have set a variable for page width but this example will not work. I have looked on the web how to do it but can't find anything. Can someone please show me the correct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` will help you out: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template

```
...page-width="{$VAR_pagewidth}"...
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, when you know how. Ill look at the reference URL you have provided in the future.